# Internationalizing Text in Yesod

Tags: haskell, internationalization, yesod, shakespeare-text

[I understand](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/internationalization) that the quasiquoter `ihamlet` will automatically call `renderMessage` for identifiers enclosed in `_{...}` (e.g. `[ihamlet|_{MsgHello}|]`).

Is there a similar method for doing i18n with the "Shakespeare" Text quasiquoters (e.g. `[st|...|]`)?

I would like to store my messages as markdown and translate them before converting to HTML, plain text (for email), etc., using Pandoc.